# Insert data from DataGridView to Access Database in C# (however it works ,syntax error in insert into statement appear)

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010, desktop-application

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow ro in dgvOrderGroup.Rows)
{        datbas.RunNonQuery("INSERT INTO [RestOrders] VALUES(" + ro.Cells[0].Value + ",'" 
         + ro.Cells[1].Value + "'," + ro.Cells[2].Value + ",'"
         + ro.Cells[3].Value + "','" + ro.Cells[4].Value
         + "','" + ro.Cells[5].Value + "','" + ro.Cells[6].Value + "')");                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your `ro.Cells[0].Value` and `ro.Cells[2].Value` (*assume they are character typed columns*) don't have single quotes in your query.

Try it like;

```
VALUES('" + ro.Cells[0].Value + "','"... + "','" + ro.Cells[2].Value + "','"
```

Would be better if we know your values and column types of course..

Comment: ro.cells[0].value   ----> Number
ro.cells[1].value   ----> Text
ro.cells[2].value   ----> Number
ro.cells[3].value   ----> Text
ro.cells[4].value   ----> Text

Comment: @ÅħmådĦusŠęįñ `ro.Cells[2].Value` is number as well? Are your `RestOrders` table has `7` column?

Comment: OffCourse , this error repeated when i use foreach or for , i think 
that error isn't in quotes or datatype

Comment: @ÅħmådĦusŠęįñ What is your query looks like when you get error? Debug your code and tell.